# GCP Dataflow streaming job/pipeline (unsuccessfully) draining for more than 24h-48h

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-spanner

I have a Dataflow job that reads from a Cloud Spanner Change Stream and writes it into GCS.

I started draining the Job 36-48h ago, but the job never left the draining state.

I then also canceled the Pipeline that initiated the Dataflow Job initially. Even after canceling the pipeline (while the Job was draining), after an additional 24h the Job is still draining, and incurring costs.

There seems to be absolutely no SLA - the job did not fail or get stuck, it simply seems like the Job is not able to drain/ resolve gracefully. I know that I can cancel and force-cancel it, but it's worrisome that the default graceful shutdown doesn't work under healthy/normal conditions.

Any suggestions on what's going on here?

Comment: Have you consulted the job logs to see what might be the root cause?

Answer (score 1):

There are two possible reasons why **Dataflow streaming jobs** are not successfully **draining**:

1. There is an **error** in your code which causes the drain to get stuck. The drain must be **forced to cancel** and fix the code errors if there are any.
2. You are using a **template** that might have a [Splittable DoFn](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/templates/provided/cloud-spanner-change-streams-to-cloud-storage) in which is **not supporting drain**.

The workaround here is to check the code and the template you are using and confirm if it is making calls to **Splittable DoFn**. You can use [Dataflow Runner v2](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/runner-v2#enable) instead because it supports Drain and re-run the job.

Comment: Thanks, that could be indeed the reason. Do you know if the default Spanner Changestream to BigQuery template is drainable, or not?

Comment: I am using `experiments=use_runner_v2` but my Dataflow job never finishes draining. It keeps reading from the Spanner change stream, and continues to write into BigQuery. The stage has changed to `Draining`, but it never completes.